# jquery radio click function to many results

Tags: jquery

I need to display value of radio button but...  if i click button again i have 2 displays.. click again and 3 displays.. need hemp.... my target is to get only 1 display...

Jquery

```
$("input[name=answ]:radio").click(function () {
        if($("input[name=answ]:radio").is(':checked')) {
            ans = $(this).val();
        elemid =  $(this).attr("id");
        $("#next").click(function(){

        alert(ans);
        ans = undefined;
        });
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div><h4 id="quest"></h4></div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt1" val="1">
        <label  for="opt1" id="ans1">a</label> <br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt2" val="2">
        <label  for="opt2" id="ans2">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt3" val="3">
        <label  for="opt3" id="ans3">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt4" val="4">
    <label  for="opt4" id="ans4">ccs</label><br>
  </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt5" val="5">
    <label  for="opt5" id="ans5">csc</label> <div id="next" style="float: right;">Next</div><br>
  </div>
```

even if i set ans for undefined still i have few results....

fiddle

[> https://jsfiddle.net/w39fs7at/31/](https://jsfiddle.net/w39fs7at/31/)

Comment: share html code also..?

Comment: Don't hook up event handlers from within event handlers (usually).

Comment: where are you adding radio button value in html in your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get selected radio button value than don't use click event of radio button instead use click event of button.

consider below snippet

```js
    
  $('#next').click(function(e){
    $radio = $('input:radio[name="answ"]:checked');
    var ans = $radio.val();
    var elemid =  $radio.attr("id");
    $("#result").text(elemid + " : " + ans);
    //console.log(ans);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h4 id="quest"></h4></div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt1" value="1">
        <label  for="opt1" id="ans1">a</label> <br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt2" value="2">
        <label  for="opt2" id="ans2">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt3" value="3">
        <label  for="opt3" id="ans3">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt4" value="4">
    <label  for="opt4" id="ans4">ccs</label><br>
  </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt5" value="5">
    <label  for="opt5" id="ans5">csc</label> <div id="next" style="float: right;">Next</div><br>
  </div>
  
  <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: wee xD thanks xD that was exactly what i need :D working perfect xD

Answer (score 1):

Use `off()`. `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached before.

```
 $("input[name=answear]:radio").off().on('click', function() {
    if ($("input[name=answear]:radio").is(':checked')) {
      ans = $(this).val();
      elemid = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#next").click(function() {

        alert(ans);
        ans = undefined;
      });
    }
  });
```

In fiddle replace `.next` with off()

```
$("#next").off().on('click',function(){
```

Working fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w39fs7at/42/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```js
$("#next").click(function() {  
  var ans = $("input[name=answ]:radio:checked").val();
  alert(ans);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><h4 id="quest"></h4></div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt1" val="1">
        <label  for="opt1" id="ans1">a</label> <br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt2" val="2">
        <label  for="opt2" id="ans2">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
    <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt3" val="3">
        <label  for="opt3" id="ans3">asd</label><br>
    </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt4" val="4">
    <label  for="opt4" id="ans4">ccs</label><br>
  </div><br>
  <div><input type="radio" name="answ" id="opt5" val="5">
    <label  for="opt5" id="ans5">csc</label> <div id="next" style="float: right;">Next</div><br>
  </div>
```

**OR** in your style, you need to unbind `$("#next").unbind('click');`

```
$(function() {

$("input[name=answ]:radio").on('change',function () {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ans = $(this).val();
        elemid =  $(this).attr("id");
        $("#next").unbind('click');
        $("#next").click(function(){            
        alert(ans);
        ans = undefined;
        });
        }
    });

});
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/w39fs7at/50/